# In the Al Cheit prayer, do we say bagalui or b'galui?

Tags: hebrew, vowels-nekudot, viduy-confession

In the Al Cheit prayer, is it

Al cheit shechatanu l'fanecha **bagalui** uvasater

or is it

Al cheit shechatanu l'fanecha **b'galui** uvasater

I get about the same number of hits whichever of the two I type into Google.

Comment: Did you look in any machzorim?

Comment: Yes, @ezra the Hebrew in the machzor I consulted is definitely bagalui – but machzorim have been known to have mistakes.

Comment: In proper Hebrew one must say B'Galuy as in https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Order_of_Prayer.4.2?vhe=Torat_Emet_370&lang=bi. "Ba-" comes as a short for "Be-Ha-" before a noun as in BaBayt.

Comment: @AlBerko Do you know who put those nekudos there?  I don't, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't the Rambam himself.  At least for בַּסָּתֶר, multiple pesukim have a patach.

Comment: @Heshy Surely it wasn't Rambam, I only comment about the contemporary Hebrew, it appears that the Nikkud in our sources went pretty wild. BTW in the Torah it didn't appear until Geonim, so it should also be taken בע"מ.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What machzorim did you check? ArtScroll? Sefaria? Tefillas Kol Peh? We need some groundwork here.

Comment: @ezra the only machzor I have is Gates of Repentance.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's one text, and it's the Reform one. You might check other sources.

Comment: @ezra, I thought my question would be a question about proper Hebrew, something others on mi yodeya know much more about than I do, and not a question about different approaches to Judaism. And if it is a question about texts and sources, then again I reckon people on mi yodeya collectively have many more texts and sources on hand than I do, and might not mind taking a few minutes to see what their sources say. I have Gates of Repentance a few feet from where I'm sitting. Maybe someone else has one or more of those other machzorim nearby, and will contribute to the discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In several places, pesukim say בַּסֵּתֶר, or at the end of a sentence בַּסָּתֶר, to mean "in private".  Examples are [Devarim 13:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.13.7) and [27:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.27.15).

<sup><sub>(Sometimes it's connected to the next word, like [Shir Hashirim 2:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.2.14), and in those cases it's with a sheva.  But that means more like "in the privacy of" so it's grammatically not comparable to viduy.)</sub></sup>

I don't see גלוי in Tanach in the sense it's used in viduy, but by analogy we can guess that it should be a patach there as well.  Also, the [Kaufmann A50](https://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/Hebrew/collections/jewish-collection/Talmud/Pages/default.aspx?IsByManuscript=True&Im_Ms=1723&Fr_Co=2&Fr_Tr=39&Pe_code=004&Mi_code=04&Li_code=1) mishnah manuscript has a patach in both בגלוי and בסתר in Avos 4:3 (left column a little below the middle).